# In parallelogram ABCD, points E and F are chosen on sides AB and CD, respectively.

Tags: geometry

In parallelogram ABCD, points E and F are chosen on sides AB and CD, respectively, so that AE = DE
and CF/DF=2/3. Find the ratio of the area of triangle BFC to the area of quadrilateral BEDF.

I'd appreciate it if someone could show a step-by-step solution to the problem. :)

Comment: Did you make a typo somewhere, please check!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

[image: ratio of triangle to quadrilateral in a parallelogram]
In parallelogram $ABCD$, given $AE=DE$ and $\frac{CF}{DF}=\frac{2}{3}$, then joining $DB$, and taking $AD$ and $\angle DAB$ as fixed, and sliding $AD$ to the right until $E$ coincides with $B$, then$$\frac{\triangle BFC}{BEDF}=\frac{2}{3}$$since triangles under the same height have areas proportional to their bases.

On the other hand, if we slide $AD$ increasingly to the left, quadrilateral $BEDF$ becomes an ever greater fraction of the lengthening trapezoid $ABFD$. Disregarding $\triangle ADE$ as negligible, then, and since a parallelogram is double a triangle of equal base and height, the ratio of $\triangle BFC$ to quadrilateral $BEDF$, as $AD$ moves to the left, approaches the ratio $\frac{\triangle BFC}{ABCD}$, i.e. diminishes indefinitely toward$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

I am not confident this answer meets the real intent of OP's problem, but based on the information given, the most I can conclude is that$$\frac{1}{3}<\frac{\triangle BFC}{BEDF}<\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Choosing these points is in general not possible:
If $AE=DE$, then $E$ has to be on the perpendicular bisector of $A$ and $D$. But $E$ is also on $AB$. Hence $E$ is on the intersection of this line and this segment. But if the segment $AD$ is too short, then there is no intersection.

[image]

In fact, if $\alpha$ is the angle at $A$, then we need $AB\ge \frac{AD} {2 \cos(\alpha)}$.